# Frequency of pairs in an array ruby

Tags: ruby

I have an array of pairs like this:

```
arr = [
  {lat: 44.456, lng: 33.222}, 
  {lat: 42.456, lng: 31.222}, 
  {lat: 44.456, lng: 33.222}, 
  {lat: 44.456, lng: 33.222}, 
  {lat: 42.456, lng: 31.222}
]
```

There are some geographical coordinates of some places. I want to get an array with these coordinates grouped and sorted by frequency. The result should look like this:

```
[
  {h: {lat: 44.456, lng: 33.222}, fr: 3}, 
  {h: {lat: 42.456, lng: 31.222}, fr: 2},
]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard ways of approaching this problem are to use [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) or a counting hash. As others have posted answers using the former, I'll go with the latter.

```
arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |f,g| g[f] += 1 }.map { |k,v| { h: k, fr: v } }
  #=> [{:h=>{:lat=>44.456, :lng=>33.222}, :fr=>3},
  #    {:h=>{:lat=>42.456, :lng=>31.222}, :fr=>2}]
```

First, count instances of the hashes:

```
counts = arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |f,g| g[f] += 1 }
  #=> {{:lat=>44.456, :lng=>33.222}=>3,
  #    {:lat=>42.456, :lng=>31.222}=>2}
```

Then construct the array of hashes:

```
counts.map { |k,v| { h: k, fr: v } }
  #=> [{:h=>{:lat=>44.456, :lng=>33.222}, :fr=>3},
  #    {:h=>{:lat=>42.456, :lng=>31.222}, :fr=>2}]
```

`g = Hash.new(0)` creates an empty hash with a default value of zero. That means that if `g` does not have a key `k`, `g[k]` returns zero. (The hash is not altered.) `g[k] += 1` is first expanded to `g[k] = g[k] + 1`. If `g` does not have a key `k`, `g[k]` on the right side returns zero, so the expression becomes:
`g[k] = 1`.

Alternatively, you could write:

```
counts = arr.each_with_object({}) { |f,g| g[f] = (g[f] ||= 0) + 1 }
```

If you want the elements (hashes) of the array returned to be in decreasing order of the value of `:fr` (here it's coincidental), tack on [Enumerable#sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by):

```
arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |f,g| g[f] += 1 }.
    map { |k,v| { h: k, fr: v } }.
    sort_by { |h| -h[:fr] }
```

Comment: this will be more memory efficient if the hash is huge, probably faster too.

Comment: `Hash.new(0)` is so frequently useful they should almost have `Hash.zero` as a shorthand for it.

Comment: I think I was wrong. With the array from question, the group_by example is about 1.5 - 2x faster. With an array of 2.5 million entries  the group_by example is over 2x faster. And it has sort + reverse on top. Mysterious are ruby's internals. My test array was the array from question duplicated a bunch of times, so it might have some effect. If the hashes would be mostly unique, it might be different.

Comment: with 100k mostly unique items they are almost as fast

Answer (score 4):

```
arr.group_by(&:itself).map{|k, v| {h: k, fr: v.length}}.sort_by{|h| h[:fr]}.reverse
# =>
# [
#   {:h=>{:lat=>44.456, :lng=>33.222}, :fr=>3},
#   {:h=>{:lat=>42.456, :lng=>31.222}, :fr=>2}
# ]
```

Comment: rather than `reverse` why not `sort_by{|h| -h[:fr]}`

Comment: @engineersmnky It is more straightforward, and in general, it is faster.

Comment: My ignorance. You are correct it definitely provides readability and does seem to perform marginally better.

Comment: @engineersmnky, of course, there's also `arr.sort { |g,h| h[:fr]<=>g[:fr] }` and `arr.max_by(arr.size) { |h} h[:fr] }` (though the latter requires a `tap`).

Comment: @CarySwoveland yes there are a million and one ways to do most things in ruby I usually try to focus on 2 things performance (as ruby suffers here to begin with over statically typed languages) and readability (where ruby really shines). That being said I ran sawa's code, my code, your mutation using sort and your answer through `fruity` and it reports: *"sort is faster than negation by 10% +/- 1%; negation and reverse are similar; reverse is faster than each_object by 30% +/- 1%"* So it seems your comment is actually faster than the answers provided and equally as readable in my opinion.

Comment: @engneersmnky, that's interesting, considering that `sort.reverse` is often reported as being fastest. I wonder why we don't have `rsort`. Could you try the new-in-v2.2 `max_by(arr.size)`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland are you asking to run `arr.tap{|a| a.max_by(a.size)`?  OR `a.instance_eval { max_by(size)} `?

Comment: @engineersmnky, I meant the former (but maybe I should have kept quiet about that).

Answer (score 2):

```
arr.group_by{|i| i.hash}.map{|k, v| {h: v[0], fr: v.size}
#=> [{:h=>{:lat=>44.456, :lng=>33.222}, :fr=>3}, {:h=>{:lat=>42.456, :lng=>31.222}, :fr=>2}]
```